# Paired listener bluecove - server side

Tags: bluetooth, connection, listener, bluecove

I actually work on a raspberry Pi with a bluetooth dongle and I need to create a bluetooth server on that devices.

I want to be notify when an other devices is pairing with the pi.

So I use the bluecove library.

I think this kind of thing isn't implements into the library.

It's there a way to do that ?

Thanks.